# Password input validation does not work inside form inputs validation code

Tags: javascript

I have a form using javascript input validation. I also wanted to add a password input to my form. But the problem now is that I ended up with two submit forms and one of them did not work. Then I tried to add my javascript validation code to the existing validation code for the form inputs. But when I ran test it did not work either. Can someone please point out what is wrong with my code? Here it is:
Here is the JavaScript code:

```
<script language="javascript">
function check() {

verify_code = document.getElementById("verify_code");
code = document.getElementById("code");
x = document.form1; 

if (x.name.value=="") {
    alert ("Please enter your Full Name!");
    document.form1.name.focus ( )
    return false;
}  
else if (x.applicant_type.value=="") {
    alert("Please select Applicant Type");
    document.form1.applicant_type.focus ( )
    return false;
}

else if(form1.pwd.value != "" && form1.pwd.value == form1.pwd1.value) {
  if(form1.pwd.value.length < 6) {
    alert("Error: Password must contain at least six characters!");
    form1.pwd.focus();
    return false;
  }
  re = /[0-9]/;
  if(!re.test(form1.pwd.value)) {
    alert("Error: password must contain at least one number (0-9)!");
    form1.pwd.focus();
    return false;
  }
  re = /[a-z]/;
  if(!re.test(form1.pwd.value)) {
    alert("Error: password must contain at least one lowercase letter (a-z)!");
    form1.pwd.focus();
    return false;
  }
  re = /[A-Z]/;
  if(!re.test(form1.pwd.value)) {
    alert("Error: password must contain at least one uppercase letter (A-Z)!");
    form1.pwd.focus();
    return false;
  }
} else {
  alert("Error: Please check that you've entered and confirmed your password!");
  form1.pwd.focus();
  return false;
}

alert("You entered a valid password: " + form1.pwd.value);

} 
else
{ return true; }
}

</script>
```

And here is my password input code:

```
<br>Password:<span class="style4">*</span> <input type="password" name="pwd"><br>
<br>Confirm Password:<span class="style4">*</span> <input type="password" name="pwd1"><br>
<span class="formnotes">(For future use if you need to modify your application) </span>
```

My password input validation works if I use this code:
    Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkForm(form)
{
if(form.username.value == "") {
  alert("Error: Username cannot be blank!");
  form.username.focus();
  return false;
}
re = /^\w+$/;
if(!re.test(form.username.value)) {
  alert("Error: Username must contain only letters, numbers and underscores!");
  form.username.focus();
  return false;
}

if(form.pwd1.value != "" && form.pwd1.value == form.pwd2.value) {
  if(form.pwd1.value.length < 6) {
    alert("Error: Password must contain at least six characters!");
    form.pwd1.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if(form.pwd1.value == form.username.value) {
    alert("Error: Password must be different from Username!");
    form.pwd1.focus();
    return false;
  }
  re = /[0-9]/;
  if(!re.test(form.pwd1.value)) {
    alert("Error: password must contain at least one number (0-9)!");
    form.pwd1.focus();
    return false;
  }
  re = /[a-z]/;
  if(!re.test(form.pwd1.value)) {
    alert("Error: password must contain at least one lowercase letter (a-z)!");
    form.pwd1.focus();
    return false;
  }
  re = /[A-Z]/;
  if(!re.test(form.pwd1.value)) {
    alert("Error: password must contain at least one uppercase letter (A-Z)!");
    form.pwd1.focus();
    return false;
  }
} else {
  alert("Error: Please check that you've entered and confirmed your password!");
  form.pwd1.focus();
  return false;
}

alert("You entered a valid password: " + form.pwd1.value);
return true;
}

</script>
```

And HTML:

```
<form ... onsubmit="return checkForm(this);">
<p>Username: <input type="text" name="username"></p>
<p>Password: <input type="password" name="pwd1"></p>
<p>Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="pwd2"></p>
<p><input type="submit"></p>
</form>
```

But when I use this code `onSubmit="return check();"` it is not working

Comment: Define "did not work".  How did it fail?  When you step through the code in a debugger, where does it go wrong?

Comment: I could make only one of the validation codes to work: either regular input validation or password validation. If I define my form action onSubmit="return check();" then my regular inputs validation worked and not the password validation but when I defined form action onSubmit="return checkForm(this);" then my password input validation worked but not the regular form input validations.

Comment: Well, your code doesn't define a function called `checkForm`, so it doesn't surprise me that wouldn't work.  But that's beside the point.  You need to describe exactly what's wrong.  Step through the code in a debugger and determine *specifically* where it behaves unexpectedly.